# Wordpress - Loop one row only show 4 result

Tags: php, wordpress

here is my custom code this will list all page from specific parent but now, how to show every row only 4 result, and last row will have class 'last'.

```
<?php

        //this is custom query for show page from specific parent page in different page        

        $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '11' AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); 
        if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>         

        <div class="child-thumb_home looping">

            <div class="property_thumb"><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, array(222,123)); ?></a></div>

            <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="property_name" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
            <?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>
            </a>

            <div class="some_desc"><?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=50&use_words=0&no_custom=1&ellipsis=%26hellip;&exclude_tags=img,p,strong'); ?></div>

            <div class="read_more"><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>">MORE INFO...</a></div>

        </div>   

        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '11' AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
```

To:

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '11' AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order LIMIT 4", 'OBJECT');
```

And these lines:

```
if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>         
    <div class="child-thumb_home looping">
```

To:

```
$num_child_pages = count($child_pages);
if ( $num_child_pages ) : for ($i = 0; $i < $num_child_pages; $i++):
    $pageChild = $child_pages[$i];
    setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>

    <div class="child-thumb_home looping <?php if ($i == $num_child_pages - 1): ?>last<?php endif; ?>">
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Try rephrasing.